# nginx proxy_pass connection refused for flask development server

Tags: docker, nginx, flask, docker-compose

**EDIT**: I needed to specify the host as 0.0.0.0 in app.run, which fixed my issue.

I've got a web-app that I'm trying to setup to use docker and docker-compose.  The backend is a flask api, front end is react, with nginx serving as a reverse-proxy, each piece running in its own container.  I'm still developing it, so I'm trying to using the flask development server to host the flask app, and the node to host the react app, with the flask container serving on port 5000, and node serving on port 3000, as is pretty standard.

It builds successfully with `docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml up --build` and each container starts up.  I can open up localhost in my browser, which loads the react app just fine.  However, when I try to login, I get a bad gateway error, which from the searching I've done, means that nginx can't find a listener where it expects one.

I've tried changing the proxy_pass value in the `/api` location, but that hasn't worked.  Do I need to specify the IP manually?  I've tried changing the ports in the `flask-api` section of my `docker-compose` file.  But that hasn't worked, either.

Where am I going wrong?

Here's my nginx configuration:

```
server {

  listen 80;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://client:3000;
    proxy_redirect    default;
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }

  location /api {
    proxy_pass        http://flask-api:5000;
    proxy_redirect    default;
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }

}
```

And here's the compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:

  flask-api:
    image: flask-translate
    build:
      context: ./flask_back_end/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    volumes:
      - "./flask_back_end/:/app"
    ports:
      - 5000:5000

  client:
    image: react-translate
    build:
      context: ./react-app/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - flask-api
    volumes:
      - './env.json:/usr/src/app/src/env.json'

  nginx:
    image: nginx-translate
    build:
      context: ./nginx/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - flask-api
      - client
```

And when I start up the containers, the flask server lets me know that it's running on `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`

If I attempt to login nginx spits out the error

`[error] 6#6: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: , request: "POST /api/user/login HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.18.0.2:5000/api/user/login", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/"`

rather than the expected forwarding of the connection to the flask development api server.

From this error message I think that the client (Which is 172.18.01) is sending a post request to localhost/api/user/login, which is attempting to forward it to 172.18.02:5000/api/user/login, but there is no listener there, so the connection is refused.

Comment: Somehow I wasn't able to find that post in my searches, thanks for linking it, it fixed my problem.  Specifying the host in as `app.run('host=0.0.0.0')` appears to be the cause of the problem.  Thanks!  Given that this appears to be a duplicate, I'm not sure I can go about marking a comment as an answer.  If you post it as an answer, I will, though.

Comment: @jakks0 Welcome to Stack Overflow! "Duplicate" questions should usually be *closed* as such, in order to avoid having helpful answers disseminated through the site. It's a normal life-cycle for some questions, and I think this one fits in this category. Questions closed as duplicate can be helpful to keep here, though, because it might help some people to find solution by using different search terms. Just to let you know, there is currently a voting by the community to close it, but I think you should have some button to accelerate the process at the top of your question (not sure).

Comment: My reputation is low enough that the button doesn't appear (It appears that you need [250](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37752/how-do-i-close-my-own-question) rep for it to appear.)